# In GCP, GSR is their anyway we can restrict one repository to an IAM User?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-source-repositories

In GCP, GSR is their anyway we can restrict one repository to an IAM User ?

Comment: You cannot restrict to a specified user. You can define which users have access. Permission can be granted via IAM roles to the project for the resource, via identities assigned to the resource and via SSH keys.

Comment: i really didnt understand it. can you pls explain how to provider specific users to it.

Comment: Read guillaume's answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a look to all your repository, you can see a user icon to manage the permissions

[image]

Grant only one user on the repository and delete all the others to achieve your use case.